# SP 2013 Rest API list setting: Users should only see their own items

Tags: list, sharepoint-server, javascript, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I create a list via the rest api. It works fine, I built it according to the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx#bk_ListCollection) (last example in this section).

As you probably know, there's a setting that users can only see and edit their own items.

**The question: Can I achieve this setting via the rest api?**

I couldn't find any endpoint or documentation on this.
If you don't know what I mean - it's the setting from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26512424/5243272) that im searching:

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you set the advanced settings of the list to **"Read items that were created by user"**, for all users that doesn't have Administrator or Total Control access.

So if you make a GET request for the URL `"/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ListName')/items"`, commom users will only see the itens that were created by themselves.

And if you want to do the same without setting **"Read items that were created by user"** in the advanced settings, you can use the URL `"/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Teste')/items?$filter=Author/Id eq" + _spPageContextInfo.userId`. But if you do this in this way, the common user that has read access to this list, can manipulate the results removing the filter or changing the Id of the creator

Hope it helps.

Comment: As I want to provide somethig like a "one-click installation" I don't want to set it manually - is there really no such endpoint?